# Excel vba how to merge this three cells?

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I try to merge three cells, and assign it to other cells, but it fails to merge third cell. Below is my code,

```
For x = 2 To LastRow_Line_Site
        With Sheets("Line_Site")
            .Cells(x, "E") = CStr(.Cells(x, "A") & .Cells(x, "B") & .Cells(x, "C"))
        End With
    Next
```

ColA:8009601022 ColB:77854  ColC:00340, and I expect to have the result like 80096010227785400340, but it turns out become 80096010227785400000

Could anyone help me on this issues?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Seems like you exceed Excels numeric precision with this. So if you format your target cell as text it should work.

Answer (score 5):

```
    With Sheets("Line_Site")
        .Cells(x, "E").NumberFormat = "@"
        .Cells(x, "E") = .Cells(x, "A").Text & .Cells(x, "B").Text & .Cells(x, "C").Text
    End With
```

Comment: Just to add to this, the reason is that Excel has a limited number precision of 15 digits. See [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) for more information. To store the number in the cell you would need to store it as a string, ensuring the number format of the cell also matches.

Comment: @Jordan Thanks mate, you save my life :)